How to Delete a Dropdown Content Control in Word Using VBA (Backspace/Delete Without Clicking Three Dots)
I'm working with Microsoft Word VBA and creating dropdown content controls in a document. I want to delete the content control (a dropdown list) by pressing the Backspace or Delete key while the content control is selected, without having to click the three dots or the control itself.
Here's my current VBA code to create a dropdown content control:
Sub MakingAList()

    Dim objCC As ContentControl

    Set objCC = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(Type:=wdContentControlDropdownList)
    
    ' List entries
    objCC.DropdownListEntries.Add "#55100 (Pool / Spa: Service Contract)"
    objCC.DropdownListEntries.Add "#55200 (Pool / Spa: Extras)"
    objCC.DropdownListEntries.Add "#55250 (Pool / Spa: Monitor)"
    
    ' Set the content control as temporary (optional, for behavior)
    objCC.Temporary = True

End Sub

Currently, when I select the dropdown and press Backspace or Delete, the control cannot be deleted unless I manually click the three dots or the content control’s name. I understand that content controls are typically treated as containers, but I am wondering if there is a way to make this process smoother. Specifically, I want the content control to be deleted using the Backspace or Delete keys without explicitly selecting the control name.
Has anyone come across this issue or know how to handle it? I’ve already tried setting the Temporary property to True, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. Any help would be appreciated!
